# AnythingSlider jQuery navigation

Tags: jquery, navigation, anythingslider

I´m trying to prevent click on the `.thumbNav li` navigation using this

```
$('.anythingSlider').delegate('.thumbNav li','click', function(){
   return false;
});
```

But it just wont work??

I quess there is a function in the script that binds the click event and perhaps that is i problem?

Perhaps there is a way to override that feature?

**Edit**: Im running this function on the `"onInitialized"` callback

This is the HTML:

```
<ul class="thumbNav" style="">
  <li class="first">
    <a class="panel1 cur" href="#">
        <span>0</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="panel2 disabled" href="#">
        <span>1</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="panel3 disabled" href="#">
        <span>2</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="panel4 disabled" href="#">
        <span>3</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="last">
    <a class="panel5 disabled" href="#">
        <span>4</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>​
```

hmmm.. acctually this works in crome (but not ff or ie):

```
$('.thumbNav li a').bind('click', function(){ 
   return false;
});
```

Comment: can you give the html of the class thumbNav li

Comment: Please read this [question][1], it explains in the first answer.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026503/anythingslider-make-nav-tabs-inactive

Comment: Based on that link I tried this:

$('.thumbNav li').bind('click', function(){
    $(this).closest('.anythingSlider').find('.anythingBase').data('AnythingSlider').gotoPage(num);
    return false;
});

No luck :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$('.anythingSlider').delegate('.thumbNav li a','click', function(){
return false;
});
```

hope this will work...

Comment: The event in anythingslider is set to the li tag so this will not work :(

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `enableNavigation` option to `false` ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/aTKzP/1073/))

```
$('#slider').anythingSlider({
    // if false, navigation links will still be visible, but not clickable.
    enableNavigation: false,
});​
```

Alternatively, you could set the `clickControls` option to an empty string:

```
$('#slider').anythingSlider({
    // Events used to activate navigation control functionality
    clickControls: "" // default is "click focusin"
});​
```